# Sort by date-time field, ignoring year, in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports, I need to be able to sort birthdays by the say of the year, and ignore the actual year, but this is proving to be difficult.

I believe I'm going to have to write a sort formula in which I add years onto the time stamp so that they're all treated as if they're from the same year, but I'm still a little confused

This is what I've got so far, but I guess I can't just declare times as a number, and I'm not sure if I could simply add them either:

```js
Local DateTimeVar DOB = {StsSt.StsSt_Birthdate};
Local DateTimeVar Jan2014 = 1388534400;
Local DateTimeVar oneYear = 31536000;

While DOB < Jan2014 Do
(
   DOB := DOB + oneYear;
);

DOB
```

SOLVED:

In the end I only needed one line of code: ToText({StsSt.StsSt_Birthdate}, "mmdd");

Comment: What do you have so far? You really just need to convert the date to a string of the form `MMDD` and use that formula to sort.

Comment: @Ryan I updated my post with the code I've got so far and the issues with it.

Comment: @Ryan While I understand what you're saying, how do I do that from the formula editor? I obviously can make it look however I want when printed on the page, but I need to make a formula to make a MMDD formatted string if I were going to sort it that way.

Comment: @Ryan I've figured it out, thanks!